# EditText box not showing on Design View - Android Studio

Tags: android

I need help as the EditText box not showing on Design View in Android Studio.

**Layout XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Snapshot. I have written code for `EditText` but its not visible on Design View.

[image]

Comment: while running it shows?. try by giving width with some 100dp value

Comment: you have set the layout _height as wrap content try setting height as 50dp

Answer (score 0):

Add style properties to edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<EditText
    style="@style/EditText.RoundBorder"        //add this line then you might be able to see
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting width as `match_parent` and height as it is. If even that does not work,try rebuilding the project. Sometimes what you add through code does not reflect immediately in the design window. Or you can delete this edit text, manually drag and drop edit text from the design window. And then you can change it's properties from the XML file